# An Issue with Application Request Routing

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

i have two web services installed on two different servers. i wanted to use Application Request Routing (ARR) to enable load balancing and availability between the two services. each of those services use message security with ClientCredentialType=username. each of them work fine "alone", but when i use the unified WS - the one i got out of ARR - it gives me a security exception, details : 
"Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the remote endpoint has failed. This may be due to absent or incorrectly specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the channel. Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint. "

isn't ARR capable of transferring the certificate information to the targeted web service? Am i missing something here?!!